# Why won't memoir show a header on the first page of a chapter?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, memoir, chapters

I want to have a header on the first page of a chapter.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makepagestyle{generalstyle}
\makeevenhead{generalstyle}{}{HEADER}{}
\makeoddhead{generalstyle}{}{HEADER}{}

\pagestyle{generalstyle}
\begin{document}

    \chapter{Can I have a header above this?}
    Some filler text for the first page. See next page...

    \clearpage So there is a header now.
\end{document}
```

Something about `memoir`'s chapters seems to suppress header output on the first page of a chapter. How can I get my header to show on the first page of the chapter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\chapter` command sets the `\thispagestyle{chapter}` explicitly which has no header by default. To trick `memoir` it's possible to use `\aliaspagestyle`, but ideally one would copy the original chapter page style first.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makepagestyle{generalstyle}
\makeevenhead{generalstyle}{}{HEADER}{}
\makeoddhead{generalstyle}{}{HEADER}{}

\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{generalstyle}

\pagestyle{generalstyle}
\begin{document}

    \chapter{Can I have a header above this? -- Yes, you can!}
    Some filler text for the first page. See next page...

    \clearpage So there is a header now.
\end{document}
```

Comment: So do chapters use `chapter` by default as their pagestyle?

Comment: @SimonKuang: Yes, unless the `article` documentclass option is used.

Comment: Is this the same as `\chapterstyle` and `\makechapterstyle`?

Comment: @SimonKuang: No, those commands set the style who the chapter title etc is set, the spacings etc. but you want to have the page headers